# Insert TradingView widget into nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, trading, tradingview-api

I am trying to insert TradingView widgets into my nextjs project, but it's not showing anything. Am  I doing something wrong here?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"

function EconomicCalendar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="tradingview-widget-container">
        <div className="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
        <div className="tradingview-widget-copyright">
          <a href="https://www.tradingview.com/" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank">
            <span className="blue-text">Track all markets on TradingView</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <Helmet>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-events.js" async>
          {`
            {
              "width": "100%",
              "height": "100%",
              "colorTheme": "dark",
              "isTransparent": false,
              "locale": "en",
              "importanceFilter": "-1,0,1",
              "currencyFilter": "AUD,USD,CAD,CNY,EUR,FRF,DEM,ITL,JPY,KRW,MYR,MXN,NZD,SGD,ZAR,ESP,CHF,TRL,GBP"
            }
          `}
          </script>
        </Helmet>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default EconomicCalendar
```

Please let me know how do people usually do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using next.js, You do not need to use react helmet to insert script tag into head. Next has it's own Script to optimize and managing third party js. Or you can write inline javascript by adding [inline scripts](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/scripts).

Take a look at official doc https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/scripts

Comment: Have you tried this with the OP's use case??  I'm having the same issue doing it "right".

Comment: OP's use case? What does that meaning?

Comment: "Original poster's use case..." meaning, in his exact situation.